# how to create one setup file for two projects in c#?

Tags: c#, add-in, shared

I have two projects
1) COM project(Shared Add-in)
and 
2) myProject(windows application)
now i want to execute both project through one setup file.
problem is the first project is shared add-in project
so how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked(v=VS.80).aspx) that Microsoft provides.